# time delay in loading information flutter firebase

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image: code1]
[image: code2]
[image: code2]

I have some trouble in resolving some time lag issues.
The first 3 photo shows the code that I have written.
[image: code4]

When I first logged in, this is the profile page that it shows without the name or email attribute.
However, if I do a hot reload, the name and email attribute appear.

[image: code5]

Can I have some ideas on how to resolve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: I think you should add "await"  when you call getCurrentUser inside initState

Comment: you should call getcurrentUser after initstate Or use provider to notify the state is changed.

Comment: how do u add await inside initState()?

Comment: you can't add await inside initState() ,but you can create new methode contain await for example getUser() async(){await a.getCureentUser();}  then call it this method in initState()

Comment: my getCurrentUser returns nothing. So I can't use the async function. I hope u can help me out thanks.

Comment: Cloud you please share the code in a manageble way, by having the code on images it complicates the other users to help you

Answer (score 0):

in your Profile screen in init ,make this change.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    a.getCurrentUser();  
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: I did what you suggested but the same problem still persists.

Comment: Are you try to return type future from the method getCurrentUser()

Comment: yep, I tried returning a future/ future<void >, both also doesn't work.

Comment: no ,try to return Future<FirebaseUser> and in profile call a.getCurrentUSer().then((user){setstate()}{nom=a.name})